# Head First Java 2nd Edition - Page 118, chapter 5

Tags: java

i'm going through an exercise called be the jvm.

However, the output that I am supposed to get is completely different to the way i have worked it out.

I reach y being 15, and my x is 7.

But the output should show 13 15 x = 6;

Here is the code:

```
 class Output {  

    public static void main (String [] args ) {  
        Output o = new Output();  
        o.go();  
    }  

    void go() {  
        int y = 7;  
        for (int x = 1; x < 8; x++) {  
            y++;  

            if ( x > 4 ) {  
            System.out.print(++y + " " );  
            }  

            if ( y > 14) {  
                System.out.println("x = " + x );  
                break;  
            } // close if   
        }  // close for  
    }  // close go  
} // close class
```

could someone walk through the code with me, and show me where I am exactly going wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also, your comments seem broken.

Comment: Ever considered to use a step-debugger by yourself °_x ?

Comment: I'm only concerned with writing it up in command line

Comment: Care to explain the problem you're trying to solve with the code you've written?

Comment: How can you reach `x = 8`? x can be 7 at most, but going step-by-step thru this code you can reach only 6. Just be patient and do what the program say, recording current variable values to a paper.

Comment: you could use debugger, to step through the program, it could be very helpful to understand what the program does

Comment: Sorry, I mean x = 7. The output only reaches x = 6 though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,

You start with a new output to call the method `go()`.

When this method runs you have two variable, `y=7` and `x=1` (`x` defined within the `for` loop).

Pay attention to the format of the `for` loop, it states `x` is initialised at 1 and only continues until `x < 8` which means when `x==7`, STOP. Don't process anything in the loop if `x` is *EQUAL* to 8.

Each loop increments `x` by one as defined by `x++`

So, stepping through the loop from the start, where `x== 1` and `y==7`
increment `y` by one  (`y++`).

now we have `x==1` and `y==8`

we can ignore the next two `if` statements as `x` is less than 4 and `y` less than 14, so back to the start of the for loop, don't forget to increment `x` by one.

So for the second loop we have:
`x==2` `y==9`.

Third loop:
`x==3` `y==10`

Fourth loop:
`x==4` `y==11` <- `x` is now 4, but not *GREATER* than 4. So on the next loop we need to enter the `if(x>4)` loop.

Fifth loop:
`x==5` `y==12` (as `y++` immediately) but then we enter the loop for when `x>4` now, therefore we `++y`. **This is probably where you made a mistake**

`++y` is similar to `y++` but increments the value, then evaluates and stores it instead of evaluating the value, then incrementing and storing it.

This outputs 13 and now `y==13`.

Sixth loop:
Same as the fifth loop (logically, enter the first if statement!)
`x==6` `y==13`

output 15 and now `y==15`, so we can enter the final loop, so we output the value of `x` for this loop,

which is 6.

We then break out and that's the end.

So the output, should be `13 15 x=6`. I hope this helps, just be aware of the difference between `++y` and `y++`.

Comment: One of the most constructive responses ever given. Thank you for your help Moedig, everyone else seems to bash me.

Comment: I see where I was going wrong. I thought y++ meant post increment, as in, only the value of y will be shown, and incremented to 8 for the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this:

```
x | y      | output
1 | 8      |
2 | 9      |
3 | 10     |
4 | 11     |
5 | 12, 13 | 13
6 | 14, 15 | 15 x = 6
```

Hope it will help you to find your mistake

Comment: how did you get 8? i thought y++ was a post incrementer.

Comment: @user1156596, after `y = 0; x = y++;` you get `y == 1` and `x == 0`. You misunderstood what post increment is.

Comment: Instead of saying i misunderstood what post increment is and wasting your time, perhaps you could have explained the difference between the two, for my benefit and other people reading. You're under no obligation to do so, but please don't waste your time in degrading me

Comment: @user1156596, don't be so offensive, noone degrading you here. You need to read more carefully or read another book if you think that post increment incrementing on a next loop iteration. No offence, just an advice

Comment: Practice makes perfect.